# download data from link javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, download

I have input type='text' where a user will provide hyperlink for google docs to be downloaded, like this

"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w_qYEgD5w-xIrnMpRMmeUycZBJiAfo4zxlVTkXb8LU4/export?gid=1865948320&format=csv"

When I pass this string as href for link with download parameter it prompts save as window and save file in csv format. If you follow the mentioned link above it will trigger file download. My goal is to save data on the client-side without "Save as" window and work with csv data. Any suggestions on how to implement this? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, on the client-side I have an input where the user provides docs.google link on a specific document with predefined csv format and I send this link to my local server on express. On the local server I make axios get request, function looks like this

```
// Request from client where I send url link
app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
  // Handle get request with link provided from client/front
  axios(req.body.payload, { method: "GET" })
    .then((response) => {
      res.status(200);
      // Data represents string of characters that I send back to client and 
      // and in my case populate table
      res.json({ file: response.data });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(404);
      res.send(error);
    });
});
```